# When to use which alignment environment?

Tags: align, amsmath, mathtools, alignat

There seem to be a whopping `align`, `aligned`, `alignedat`, `alignat`, `xalignat`, `xxalignat` and `falign` in `amsmath` / `mathtools` - some also in there starred version.

I just find sloppy statements like:

- "[The advantage of aligned is the much better horizontal and vertical spacing.](http://mirrors.ctan.org/obsolete/info/math/voss/mathmode/Mathmode.pdf)", p.52
- "[Similar to align, to be used inside another mathematics environment.](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Advanced_Mathematics#Other_environments)"

**When do I use which align environment (best practice)?**

**What are the exact differences between them?**

**Why does the environment exist at all (example use case, if applicable)?**

**Which should I avoid and why?**

[image: different align environments]

In particular, what are the differences between

- `align` and `xalignat`
- `xxalignat` and `flalign*`
- `alignat*` and `alignedat`

[image: different align environments 2]

and what is the semantic difference / different use-case between `align*` and `aligned`? When do I use which?

[image: different align environments 3]

It appears to me as if `align` is intended to be used to print *independent* columns whereas `alignat` is intended to align *dependent* columns (e.g. equations [rows] aligned by their operators [columns]).

Thanks a lot!

---

**Appendix**

Source:

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathtools,onlyamsmath}

\newlength{\Short}
\newlength{\LShort}
\newlength{\Long}
\setlength{\Short}{.05\columnwidth}
\setlength{\LShort}{.08\columnwidth}

\newcommand{\env}[2][]{\begin{#2}#1
    \framebox[\Short]{} &= \framebox[\LShort]{} & \framebox[\LShort]{} &= \framebox[\LShort]{} & \framebox[\LShort]{} &= \framebox[\LShort]{}\\
    \framebox[\Short]{} &= \framebox[\Short]{}  & \framebox[\Short]{}  &= \framebox[\Short]{}  & \framebox[\Short]{}  &= \framebox[\Short]{}
\end{#2}}

\newcommand{\Align}[2][]{\paragraph{#2}\env[#1]{#2}}
\newcommand{\mAlign}[2][]{\paragraph{#2}\[\env[#1]{#2}\]}


\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\enlargethispage{\baselineskip}

\Align{align*}
\Align{align}

\Align[{3}]{alignat*}
\Align[{3}]{alignat}

\mAlign{aligned}

\mAlign[{3}]{alignedat}

\Align[{3}]{xalignat}
\Align[{3}]{xxalignat}

\Align{flalign*}
\Align{flalign}

\newpage

\Align{align}
\Align[{3}]{xalignat}

\Align[{3}]{xxalignat}
\Align{flalign*}

\Align[{3}]{alignat*}
\mAlign[{3}]{alignedat}

\Align{align*}
\mAlign{aligned}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You missed `multline`. I'd say that it is opinion based, you use the tool best suited for whatever you're typesetting. For most of my manuscript editing I tend to use `equation` for one-liners and `align` for the rest (never use `align` for one-liners, trained eyes can spot them in the PDF). Occasionally I'll use `gather` and `alignedat` as well. I also use `aligned` or alignedat` for some constructions and rarely `split.` The rest I never use (especially not `multline` and `eqnarray`)

Comment: @daleif I left out `multline` intentionally. I did non write it explicitly but these are all *centering* environments. `multline` is unique in this sense as it left-aligns the first line, right-aligns the last and centers the rest. Adding `multline`, I would also need to list `gather`, `gather*`, `gathered`, `split` and possibly others. I am curious about those as well but I thought it might be overkill for the question.

Comment: My gut feeling is that the `*ed*`-environments are "internal" ones that might be used within other environments but are not intended to be used stand-alone and that the `x*`-environments are legacy stuff -- so that `align`, `alignat` and `flalign` as well as their starred counterparts remain. But since most of the stuff about LaTeX on the internet is a subjective myth, I'd like to have that confirmed by someone with more experience. And I'm also curious about the history and circumstances of those environments. :)

Comment: the naming scheme that `-ed` ones are for alignments to be used within an outer math display is well documented in the amsmath documentation, you don't need "gut feeling" or to believe in myths

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I read the User's Guide prior to asking the question and I now read it again and still can't find it there. Information about the -ed environments is sparsely sprinkled over the complete document but afaics there is not concise 'These are the characteristics of -ed environments' or alike - they just pop up here and there. If it would have been well enough documented for me, I wouldn't have asked here. Due to the former and that they're not listed under 3.1, my gut feeling resulted in 'not intended for the general end-user'. Same for the x- versions.

Comment: @Suuuehgi first paragraph of 3.7 is what I had in mind "alignment building blocks" it's actually not as clear as I remembered, but does distinguish full displays (described in the previous section) from the -ed ones which make a term within an equation. They are not in 3.1 as they do no make math displays, they have their own section, 3.7

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`amsmath` is derived from AMSTeX (`amstex.tex`) which does not have `*` forms but otherwise has mostly similar naming, including the `x-` variants. The environments that start math displays are documented in `amsmath.pdf` as

```
%    \begin{environment}{align}
%    \begin{environment}{align*}
%    \begin{environment}{flalign}
%    \begin{environment}{flalign*}
%    \begin{environment}{alignat}
%    \begin{environment}{alignat*}
%    \begin{environment}{xalignat}
%    \begin{environment}{xalignat*}
%    \begin{environment}{xxalignat}
%    The definitions of the various \env{align} environments are quite
%    straight-forward.
%
%    \begin{macrocode}
\newenvironment{alignat}{%
  \start@align\z@\st@rredfalse
}{%
  \endalign
}
\newenvironment{alignat*}{%
  \start@align\z@\st@rredtrue
}{%
  \endalign
}
\newenvironment{xalignat}{%
  \start@align\@ne\st@rredfalse
}{%
  \endalign
}
\newenvironment{xalignat*}{%
  \start@align\@ne\st@rredtrue
}{%
  \endalign
}
\newenvironment{xxalignat}{%
  \start@align\tw@\st@rredtrue
}{%
  \endalign
}
\newenvironment{align}{%
  \start@align\@ne\st@rredfalse\m@ne
}{%
  \math@cr \black@\totwidth@
  \egroup
  \ifingather@
    \restorealignstate@
    \egroup
    \nonumber
    \ifnum0=`{\fi\iffalse}\fi
  \else
    $$%
  \fi
  \ignorespacesafterend
}
\newenvironment{align*}{%
  \start@align\@ne\st@rredtrue\m@ne
}{%
  \endalign
}
\newenvironment{flalign}{%
  \start@align\tw@\st@rredfalse\m@ne
}{%
  \endalign
}
\newenvironment{flalign*}{%
  \start@align\tw@\st@rredtrue\m@ne
}{%
  \endalign
}
```

Where you can see they are all variants of the same underlying code.

Comparing, say `xalignat*` and `align*` You see

```
\start@align\@ne\st@rredtrue
\start@align\@ne\st@rredtrue\m@ne
```

so `align*` is just `\xalignat*` except -1 is supplied as the number of column pairs, which makes the environment not require a `{3}` argument for 3 column pairs in your example, it just does the right thing.  As such, the `x...` versions are not really needed and are not documented at all in the user level `amslguide.pdf` documentation.

As documented, the `-ed` named environments do not start a math display and must be started within an outer math environment. They have more in common with `array` or `matrix`, except that they set their entries with left and right, rather than centred, alignment and use displaystyle rather than textstyle.

Comment: Nice one, +1. But, did you mean `amstex.sty` (or `amstex.tex`)?

Comment: @gusbrs no amstex is `amstex.tex` (predates latex 2.09) `/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/amstex/base/amstex.tex` (`amstex.sty` was first version of the merge of that with latex, that became amsmath)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, I meant what @barbarabeeton mentioned, the last "t". There exists `amstext.sty` but, if I recall correctly, it's the one which defines the `\text` macro.

Comment: @gusbrs ah, sorry.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! Now it gets clearer to me. Esp. the textstyle / displaystyle information I can not find within the User's Guide. Two questions remain: **1** What do you mean with left and right (compared to centered) alignment, when the cell is always the size of the content? **2** Could you tell me what the `aligned` env. is about? It is not part of the listings on p.62 of the implementation notes you quoted above.

Comment: @Suuuehgi as I say above `aligned` like all environments ending `ed` does not make a display (so not in the list I showed) it makes a term within an equation, like `matrix` but with the column alignment like `align`, `matrix` is like `\begin{array}{ccccc}`  `aligned`,  is like `\begin{array}{rlrlrl}`